# Log not being recorded for quickfix c++ Session

Tags: quickfix

I am currently running a FIX initiator and succesfully connecting to an acceptor. The problem is, no log is being recorded. The .cfg for the application is written below.

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=2
ResetOnLogon=Y
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=logging
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=Y



# standard config elements

[SESSION]
# inherit ConnectionType, ReconnectInterval and SenderCompID from default
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=INIT
TargetCompID=ACCEPT
SocketConnectHost=xxx
SocketConnectPort=xxx
HeartBtInt=30
DataDictionary=FIX44MD.xml

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=INIT
TargetCompID=ACCEPT1
SocketConnectHost=xxx
SocketConnectPort=xxx
HeartBtInt=30
DataDictionary=FIX44OMS.xml
```

The excerpt from the code which initiates the connection is written below:

```
    std::string file = argv[ 1 ];
    FIX::SessionSettings settings( file );
    Application application;
    FIX::FileStoreFactory storeFactory( settings );
    FIX::ScreenLogFactory logFactory( settings );
    FIX::SocketInitiator initiator( application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory);

    initiator.start();
    application.run();
    initiator.stop();
```

I'm pretty sure the problem isn't related to writing permissions, as i am running the app as an administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using a `ScreenLogFactory`, which, as its name implies, only logs to the screen (e.g. your terminal).

Change it to a `FileLogFactory` and you should be in business.